# Script to change downloaded mac wallpaper automatically?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automation, microsoft, wallpaper

I want to change my mac wallpaper daily with microsoft bing images. 
I found [this script](https://github.com/thejandroman/bing-wallpaper) that download the daily picture automatically, but I sill have to set the wallpaper automatically.
**Is it possible to write a script** (either terminal or applescript) **that set the downloaded picture as wallpaper automatically?**

Answer (score 4):

You could use this script taken from [here](http://pastebin.com/wHr1pV7k).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import md5
import pprint
import sys
import subprocess
from time import strftime
from urllib import URLopener
from urllib2 import urlopen
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

# Defines source and destination of image
rss_feed = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages';
dst_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures/DeskFeed/')

SCRIPT = """/usr/bin/osascript<<END
tell application "Finder"
set desktop picture to POSIX file "%s"
end tell
END"""


def set_desktop_background(destination):
subprocess.Popen(SCRIPT%destination, shell=True)

def parseFeed(rss):
destination = "%s%s.jpg" % (dst_dir, strftime( "%y-%m-%d"))
if os.path.exists(destination):
sys.exit(0)



try:
rss_contents = urlopen( rss )
except:
print "Failed to read rss feed %s" % rss
return
rss_src = rss_contents.read()
rss_contents.close()
dom = parseString( rss_src )
firstitem = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')[0]
link = firstitem.getElementsByTagName( 'enclosure' )[0].getAttribute('url')
URLopener().retrieve(link, destination)
set_desktop_background(destination)


def main():
parseFeed(rss_feed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

The only downside is you would need to make a cron job to run it every day.

Answer (score 3):

Solved! I used the [Bing Wallpaper.app found here](https://github.com/thejandroman/bing-wallpaper/tree/master/Tools) that does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad we could help out :)

Comment: Sometimes [talking to the duck](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [command-line app](https://github.com/sindresorhus/wallpaper) that can change the desktop wallpaper from the terminal:

```
$ npm install -g wallpaper
$ wallpaper unicorn.jpg
```